# Replication of digits in a string using regex sub (Python)

Tags: python, regex

I have a `s="gh3wef2geh4ht"`. How can I receive `s="gh333wef22geh4444ht"` by using sub. I have tried this **regexp**. what I am doing wrong?

```
s=re.sub(r"(\d)",r"\1{\1}",s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a regular expression pattern in the replacement pattern. The `{...}` does not copy the text captured in Group 1 *n* times. You need to use a lambda expression or a callback method in the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to achieve what you want:

```
import re
s = 'gh3wef2geh4ht'
s=re.sub(r"\d", lambda m: m.group() * int(m.group()), s)
print(s)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bNa1L4)

Note you do not need any capturing groups here, as the whole match is already available in Group 0.

Here, `m` is assigned with the curren match object, `m.group()` is the text value of the match and `int(m.group())` is the digit cast to an `int`. Thus, when `3` is matched, the lambda expression does just `"3" * 3` and returns as the replacement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `lambda` function to capture the matched digits and repeat it:

```
s="gh3wef2geh4ht"
​
re.sub(r'(\d)', lambda m: m.group(1) * int(m.group(1)), s)
# 'gh333wef22geh4444ht'
```